# Trying to reinstalling .net framework 4 on windows server 2003 SP2

Tags: windows-server-2003, .net

I had a problem with an application that was using .net framework 4. So I tried to fix the installation but it didn't solved. So I proceed to uninstall the framework and install it again.
But then the problems started... the setup just wouldn't finish to download the framework. So i tried the full installer, and then it got stuck (freezes) at "installing client profile"...

The server works well but the installation progress bar just stays at the same place (but the "wheel" keeps turning, like it was doing something, but stays like this for hours...)

I tried the .net clean unistall software but the problem remains. I'm all out of ideas...

I've searched the web but couldn't solve the problem with any solution I found...

Any ideas on how to force the installation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

**Version 2 of the Microsoft .NET Framework repair tool is available**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2698555

**Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool**
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135

I'm also not entirely clear on "..the setup just wouldn't finish to download the framework".  Are you using the full/standalone installer?  With that package, it should not need to download anything.

**Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Standalone Installer)**
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your quick reply. When I said that the setup wouldn't finish, it was when I was not using the full/standalone installer, then I changed to the full/standalone one. I tried now the repair tools you gave me but they didn't work... I think it's a problem with mcafee, I'm diong some test and then I'll post here the results